# Feynman rule for scalar theory with derivatives

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I have a Lagrangian with a term $$\frac{1}{2}\phi(a)\phi(b)\partial_\mu\phi(c)\partial^\mu\phi(d) \to -\frac{1}{2}cd\phi_a\phi_b\phi_c\phi_d$$ 
The scalar fields are real and have mass. Now, my usual method for calculating this is to assign the four incoming scalar fields momenta $p, p', k, k'$ and then just do "combinatorics" - placing, for example, $p\to a, p' \to b$ etc. In so doing, I do get $4!$ possible combinations, and my result for the vertex rule is
$$-2i\big[kk' + p'k' + p'k +pk' + pk + pp'\big]$$

I have also gone through this with functional derivatives in painful detail, and my result is the same. However, it should be 
$$-i\big[(p+k)^2 + (p+k')^2 + (p+p')^2\big]$$
again with the convention of all momenta incoming. So my question is - where have I gone wrong? I thought I had understood this vertex rule stuff, but apparently not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does a, b, c, d mean? Are those four different fields? What does cd multiplied by the fields mean?